# Save Current DOM to file on server using PHP, Ajax, jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom, domdocument

I've searched everywhere, but each solution I find hasn't worked for me so far.

I am building a website app where people can create their own slideshow. When the user clicks the save button I want the current DOM to be saved as an HTML file on my web server.

The first method I tried uses Ajax, but nothing gets returned:

**AJAX**

```
 function chk() { 
  var elHtml = document.getElementById('dropzone').innerHTML;
  console.log("inside chk");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://www.tap-plus.org/wp-content/themes/Avada/softwarefiles/savefile.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {functionname: 'write_to_server', arguments: [elHtml] },
    cache:false,
    success: function (obj) {
    if( !('error' in obj) ) {
      $('#msg').html(obj);
    }
    else {
    console.log(obj.error);
    }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

**savefile.php**

```
function write_to_server($html_code) { 
    $html_string = $_POST['arguments'][0];
    var_dump($html_string);
    echo 'test';
}
```

**html**
`<input type="submit" id="saving" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Save2" onclick="return chk()"/>`

The above method returns nothing. The second method I tried was fetching the current DOMDocument with `loadHTMLFile` of the current website URL. That returned null.

**DOMDocument**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://https://www.tap-plus.org/tapplus-software/');
var_dump($dom);
```

result:

```
object(DOMDocument)#3045 (35) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL
```

Also, I want to accomplish this without the page reloading, if possible. Since ideally if someone hits the save button on a slideshow they are working on they won't want the page to suddenly reload. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what the next steps would be to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not returning JSON from `savefile.php`.

Comment: Why are you doing `var_dump($html_string)` when the script is supposed to return JSON?

Comment: Should I remove the dataType: JSON from the ajax? I was just trying to parse the HTML to a string that I can save as a file.

Comment: If you remove that then you won't be able to do `if (!('error' in obj))` since you're not returning a JSON object.

Comment: How about using this: var elHtml = $('#dropzone').val();

Comment: Just added that, no different unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Here was the solution for me to click a save button, return the html code of a particular element and prevent the page from refreshing:

AJAX

```
var url = '/savefile.php';
function chk() { 
  var elHtml = document.getElementById('outer-content').innerHTML;
  console.log("inside chk");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {myCode: elHtml },
    success: function (obj) {
      console.log("success outer");
        $('#msg').html(obj);
        console.log("success");
    }
  });
  console.log(url);
  return false;
}
```

PHP

```
          $html_val = $_POST[ 'myCode' ];

          var_dump($html_val);
```

It was actually a lot simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP should echo JSON, not the HTML input.

```
function write_to_server($html_code) { 
    $html_string = $_POST['arguments'][0];
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Data saved successfully'));
}
```

And the jQuery code should display the message.

```
    if( !('error' in obj) ) {
        $('#msg').html(obj.msg);
    }
    else {
        console.log(obj.error);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I didn't get anything returned.

Comment: Check the Response section of the Network tab to make sure you're not returning anything before or after the JSON.

Comment: Only thing I see in the network tab is for bootstrap and jquery UI.

Comment: I see the console.log for my "inside chk" print statement but that is it

Comment: You don't see it sending to `savefile.php`? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have a var_dump('test') statement in the function write_to_server but that isn't showing up either. No console errors that I can see either.

Comment: Would the DOMDocument method be a better solution?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference. Your problem is not with how you're parsing the parameter, it's with how you send the result.

Comment: The DOMDocument method isn't even using the parameter that you're sending in the AJAX call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212209/discussion-between-chris-mcglade-and-barmar).